Button in a table cell to open a modal dialog
I have a table with some PHP and a form. Here is a part of it which shows that a button is placed in a cell:
if ($giorno == "ven"){
echo '<td>'.$qres["ven_1"].'</td>;
echo '<td>';
?>
<form action="?" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" id="ven_1" name="ven_1" value="<?php echo $qres["ven_1"];?>">
 <button type="submit" class="btn" id="ts">click me</button>
</form>
<?php
echo '</td>';
}

Below the table I have a script which triggers a modal dialog.
It basically counts some cells and shows the number in a dialog.
<script>
const re1 = /^[0-9][A-Z]/;
const re2 = /^c[0-9]/;

const actives = $('td').filter(function() {
  const text = $(this).text();
  const makeActive = text.match(re1) !== null;
  $(this).toggleClass('active', makeActive);
  $(this).toggleClass('compresenza', text.match(re2) !== null);
  return makeActive;
}).length;

$('<div id="messaggio"></div>').html(`${actives}`).dialog({
    title: 'Title',
    width: '300px',
    buttons: {},
    modal: true,
});
</script>

As it is, the dialog opens when the HTML page is loaded.
I would like to set the dialog to autoOpen: false and open it only when the button in the table above is clicked on.
What is the correct procedure to achieve this?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

You can put the dialog opening into a function, like
function openDialog(actives) {
    $('<div id="messaggio"></div>').html(`${actives}`).dialog({
        title: 'Title',
        width: '300px',
        buttons: {},
       modal: true,
    });
}

and create an event, like
document.querySelector('form button#ts').addEventListener("click", function() {
    //TODO: Make sure actives is reachable and properly initialized here
    openDialog(actives);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

EDIT:
Your button submits the form, this is why your dialog appears only for a fraction of a second. To fix this problem you will need to e.preventDefault() and/or return false; inside the click handler that will prevent the form from being submitted.

I guess I might miss something (in the event creation), as the dialog appears for a sec and then disappears immediately.

@Alex if you put debugger; just after your call of openDialog, is the popup still open at this state, or was it already closed?

With debugger; it won't show.

@Alex is there a particular reason why you assign .length as the value of actives? It will contain a number then.

Yes, actives is a number.

@Alex I think I know what the problem is. Let me try something first.

@Alex okay, so your form was being submitted, which sends a request to the server and displays the response. This is why stuff disappeared for you. You will need to avoid submitting the form if you want to display the dialog (see my edit to the answer), or the response of your POST should display the dialog, which would be the alternative. It's up to you to decide what works for you best.

Interesting. With e.preventDefault(); the dialog appears correctly but the data are not sent forward to the following part of HTML. With return false; the dialog appears and disappears (you can see the behaviour in the link:  https://daado.altervista.org/assenza_CON_MODAL_DA_MIGLIORARE.php) although data are sent forward to the following HTML.

@Alex by data "sent forward" do you mean you want to actually post stuff to the server?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
